# Concatenating very large arrays loaded from JLD2 in Julia without risk of memory error

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, julia, hdf5

I have saved a large amount of very large 1D arrays in a JLD2 file, which can be called using the following code:

```
using JLD2

file = jldopen("data.jld2", "r")
array_1 = file["array_1"]
close(file)
```

Assume there are, say, 10^6 arrays, saved in the `data.jld2` file in the format of `array_1`, `array_2`, etc., up to `array_1000000`.

I want to save two new arrays into the same JLD2 file:

1. The concatenated array `cat(array_1, array_2, ..., dims=1)`
2. The array of arrays `[array_1, array_2, ...]`

Since there are very large amount of arrays, when I save them as variables in the code, there will be huge risks that the RAM cannot cope with the size of the data and would cause a memory error. Is there a way to save these arrays directly into the JLD2 file to avoid a memory error no matter how large each of the arrays is and how many arrays I need to handle?

Comment: Lets say that you are able to use mmap() to create such a file.  Is there going to be a problem with jldopen() opening that file in the future? You do not want to make a file so big that you cannot use it. On the other hand, if jldopen can read a file that size into memory, it probably can create it as well, without resorting to mmap or database tricks.